# When Web page is displayed in a div, Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed

Tags: php

A url is being displayed in a div as shown below

```
    <div id="ipage">
<? $url = "http://www.yahoo.com"; 
        $file1 = fopen($url, "r");
        $content = file_get_contents($url); 
         echo $content;
?>
    </div>
```

And I receive this error
Webpage error details

Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

Bright idea to solve this.

Thanks
Jean

[EDIT]

I am going to use jQuery here.  Is there anyway to hide javascript errors, so the rest of the code excute, without flaws.

Comment: You have not said why you are trying to embed another web page within yours, so I will assume the simplest possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to load the page inside an `iframe` tag instead of a `div`:

```
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure about the error, but obviously, if you do it this way, you generate HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="ipage">
   <html>
      <head>
         <!-- ... -->
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- ... -->
      </body>
   </html>
</div>
```

This is not valid HTML so I would not expect the browser to handle such.

Comment: @Jean: Well that is what I wanted to say. If you don't tell us what you want to achieve, it is difficult to help. I just wanted to point out, why it is not working and that any approach that generates HTML like this will not work.

Comment: I just want the error to go away or hid the error to execute the rest of the code